# Can I transform the pandas dataset to one row per WorkItemCnt in fewer lines of code?

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone have suggestions for using fewer lines of code so that each WorkItemCnt is in it's own row?

Starting off with this dataset

```
print (dfGaps)
```

prints out this

```
       Lab Location|  MC ADO|  MC Link|  HW Received or Expected|
        -----------| ------ | ------- | ----------------------- |
0|            Q Lab|       0|        0|                        1|   
1|            R Lab|      13|       13|                       18|   
2|            V Lab|       0|        0|                        2|   
3|            Z Lab|       0|        0|                        6|
```

Can I achieve the following with fewer lines of code?

```
df1 = dfGaps[['Lab Location', 'MC ADO']]
df1 = df1.assign(FieldName = 'MC ADO').rename(columns = {'MC ADO':'WorkItemCnt'})

df2 = dfGaps[['Lab Location', 'MC Link']]
df2 = df2.assign(FieldName = 'MC Link').rename(columns = {'MC Link':'WorkItemCnt'})


df3 = dfGaps[['Lab Location', 'HW Received or Expected']]
df3 = df3.assign(FieldName = 'HW Received or Expected').rename(columns = {'HW Received or Expected':'WorkItemCnt'})


dfN = df1.append([df2, df3]).reset_index()
print (dfN)
```

```
     index|     Lab Location|  WorkItemCnt|                FieldName|
    ------| --------------- | ----------- | ----------------------- |
0 |      0|       Quanta Lab|            0|                   MC ADO|
1 |      1|      Redmond Lab|           13|                   MC ADO|
2 |      2|  Veritas TPE Lab|            0|                   MC ADO|
3 |      3|           ZT Lab|            0|                   MC ADO|
4 |      0|       Quanta Lab|            0|                  MC Link|
5 |      1|      Redmond Lab|           13|                  MC Link|
6 |      2|  Veritas TPE Lab|            0|                  MC Link|
7 |      3|           ZT Lab|            0|                  MC Link|
8 |      0|       Quanta Lab|            1|  HW Received or Expected|
9 |      1|      Redmond Lab|           18|  HW Received or Expected|
10|      2|  Veritas TPE Lab|            2|  HW Received or Expected|
11|      3|           ZT Lab|            6|  HW Received or Expected|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `melt`:

```
df.melt(id_vars='Lab Location', value_name='WorkItemCnt', var_name='FieldName')
```

Output:

```
   Lab Location                FieldName  WorkItemCnt
0         Q Lab                   MC ADO            0
1         R Lab                   MC ADO           13
2         V Lab                   MC ADO            0
3         Z Lab                   MC ADO            0
4         Q Lab                  MC Link            0
5         R Lab                  MC Link           13
6         V Lab                  MC Link            0
7         Z Lab                  MC Link            0
8         Q Lab  HW Received or Expected            1
9         R Lab  HW Received or Expected           18
10        V Lab  HW Received or Expected            2
11        Z Lab  HW Received or Expected            6
```

P.S. And if you want to keep `index` as well:

```
(df
     .reset_index()
     .melt(
         id_vars=['index', 'Lab Location'],
         value_name='WorkItemCnt',
         var_name='FieldName'))
```

Output:

```
    index Lab Location                FieldName  WorkItemCnt
0       0        Q Lab                   MC ADO            0
1       1        R Lab                   MC ADO           13
2       2        V Lab                   MC ADO            0
3       3        Z Lab                   MC ADO            0
4       0        Q Lab                  MC Link            0
5       1        R Lab                  MC Link           13
6       2        V Lab                  MC Link            0
7       3        Z Lab                  MC Link            0
8       0        Q Lab  HW Received or Expected            1
9       1        R Lab  HW Received or Expected           18
10      2        V Lab  HW Received or Expected            2
11      3        Z Lab  HW Received or Expected            6
```